# Django queryset of related objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Having the following model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Company)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(to=Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I would like to get a `queryset` of all persons in a company

Using

```
def persons_by_company(company_name):
    l = []
    for d in Department.objects.filter(company__name=company_name):
        for p in d.persons:
            l.append(p)
    return l
```

would be

1. slow
2. does return a list and not a queryset (is not filterable, etc)

What would be the way to get a queryset here?

Comment: How about this `Person.objects.filter(departement__company__id=company_id)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I think it's quite simple with just

```
Person.objects.filter(departement__company__id=company_id).distinct()
```

or with the company name:

```
Person.objects.filter(departement__company__name__iexact=company_name).distinct()
```

Your function would become:

```
def persons_by_company(company_name):
    return Person.objects.filter(departement__company__name__iexact=company_name).distinct()
```

It returns a *queryset* and it's faster. I use `iexact` to avoid case sensitive.

UPDATED:
`.distinct()` Just to remove duplicate entries.

Comment: I don't think it works - department is a many-to-many field (A person can have multiple departments

Comment: Correct, but you use *department* just to lookup to company, it will just list all person entries linked to the given company name. Did you test it?

Comment: You were right, in my case there is more constraint to the department, do I use a Q query then? i.E. I would like to get it from `Department.objects.filter(name__icontains="A")`

Comment: Yes, you can use it to lookup with different fields

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work - if the person is in two departments of the company, it gets returned twice

Comment: Ok. you can just use `.distinct()` just to remove duplicate entries. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

First you must have foreign key binded to your company or department

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Company, related_name="department_company_key")

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_department = models.ForeignKey(
        'Department',
        related_name="person_department_key"
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
```

then in your function:

```
def persons_by_company(company_name):
    l = []
    for d in Department.objects.filter(company__name=company_name):
        for p in d.person_department_key.all(): # You also apply some filter()
            l.append(p) # Remember This will append object  not  string or dictionary
    return l
```

**Don't forget that related name must be unique**

Comment: (My real model is a lot more complex, it was just a minimal example). I cannot change the model - especially yours is technically different - It has an N to 1 Relation Person to Department, my model has an M to N relation

Comment: Does in your model one person  ccacn have more than one  department?